# how to design a database/ Django Models for a an app which must handle purchase of licences

Tags: python, database, django, database-design

I'm designing an App which mus handle the act of a user purchasing a Licence. I'm not focusing on the Authentication part, but only on the transaction part of the process
Basically i'd define these models:

1) User - Which holds the data of the user
2) Licence - Which holds the data for the licence. This will have a many to one relationship with the user as a user can purchase multiple licences, and a one to one relationship with the Transaction ( one Licence is related to only one transaction )
3) Payment methods - Which hold payment methods ( basically credit cards ). This has a many too one relationship with User
4) Transaction - Which holds the data of the transaction, and has a one to one relationship with the user ( one transaction is done by one user only ) and a one to one relationship with the Payment Methods ( one transaction is associated with one payment method )

Do  you think this is right?
I'm adding some redundancy by adding a relationship between the User and the Licence ( which could be connected only by the transaction ) but i think it saves some JOINS in the SQL.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about saving joins in the SQL. With stuff like this, I do like to semi-duplicate data though. Into the License or Transaction, I'd probably pop in things the user's then-email, ip-address, etc.  The rationale is that at some point the user may likely change emails, and if you have any order issues come up you will need to reference the details @ time of sale ( vs the user's current info )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same schema for any kind of product order system:

A *customer party* places a *sales order* with a *vendor party* for one or more *catalog items*, one of which may be a *sales agreement*, such as a software license.

The vendor party *invoices* (requests payment from) the *bill-to party* (who may be the same as the customer party) at a *bill-to address*, one or more times. The bill-to party makes one or more *payments* against that particular invoice, until the invoice is *paid*.

The payment does not necessarily coincide with the *shipment* or *delivery* of the sales order item. You could ship the sales order item before or after the invoice is paid.

A sales order item is *shipped* to the *ship-to party* at the *ship-to address* (which could be an IP address or email address), and is hopefully *delivered*, at which point you *accrue revenue*.

This should get you started:

```
PARTY
id
type {organization, individual, automated_agent}
name
...


ADDRESS
id 
type {email, web, facility, telephone}
...


SALES_ORDER
id
order_date
customer_id -> party
vendor_id -> party
bill_to_id -> party
bill_to_address_id -> address


CATALOG_ITEM
id
type {good, service, agreement}
...


SALES_ORDER_ITEM
id
sales_order_id -> sales_order
catalog_item_id -> catalog_item
ship_to_id -> party
ship_to_address_id -> address
price
quantity


PAYMENT_METHOD
id
name


# whether payment has a key to invoice depends on whether you allow cross-invoice payments and/or partial payments
PAYMENT
id
payment_date 
payer_id -> party
payee_id -> party
amount
method -> payment_method
```

elided:

```
shipment_request
shipment
delivery
invoice
invoice_payment
```